# ApplicationDbContext instance return null

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I was working on my project and it was working good and i did not edit any code and now when i run project every where i use my context thrown 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.
For example :

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
Response.Write(db.Transactions.FirstOrDefault().Status);
```

here thrown an error that says db is null.
or :

```
var manager = new UserManager();
ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

says that user is null but i have database and i have user!
or even in Application_Start in `Global.ascx` file :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new UsersDbInitializer());
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

it says db is null! Everywhere i use `ApplicationDbContext` it returns null.

Comment: Is `ApplicationDbContext` null, or is some other code that's called in the constructor null? You need to debug your program to determine what's going on. We can't do that for you.

Comment: in debug when it is running db.Database.Initialize(true) thrown error, it says that db is null

Comment: `db` cannot be null if you initialize it as you've shown `var db = new ApplicationDbContext();`. You're leaving *something* out of the question.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: So the problem isn't that db is null. It's that you're getting an error from some method call, but you haven't said what that method call is.

Answer (score -1):

I found my mistake, i have created an Asp page : GroupSend.aspx and i have a class in Models folder GroupSend.cs in my ApplicationDbContext i wrote

```
public DbSet<GroupSend> GroupSends {get;set;}
```

i changed it to

```
public DbSet<Models.GroupSend> GroupSends {get;set;}
```

now it's working.
Thanks all

Comment: That wouldn't have anything to do with the issue mentioned in your question.